# Which Grep command can I use to combine 2 lines of text in BBEdit?

Tags: text-processing, editors

Using ***BBEDIT Grep command (Find & Replace Functionality)*** Is there a way to merge 2 lines of text in a single line for 2 columns?

For example:

```
Ryan Muramatsu
Corporate Venturing Co-Lead at Tokio Marine
```

The result should be:

```
(Column1)Ryan Muramatsu (Column2)Corporate Venturing Co-Lead at Tokio Marine
```

Comment: Are those the only two lines in your input file and what delimiter are you using to define a column. Can't be general whitespace or else your output would be three columns. Also, you don't need to yell in your title - lowercase works well and is less intense.

Comment: Thank you for reminding, I've changed the title of this question to proper case, I've also changed the example as well.

Comment: How do you define a "column"?  What separates columns?

Comment: Hi, I recall TextWrangler (an earlier BareBones product) had a `#!` Menu item. Also, have you looked at the BareBones website? There's a pic showing how to run an `awk` command: https://www.barebones.com/images/bbedit/run-unix-command-lg.png . See: https://www.barebones.com/products/bbedit/benefitsexercise.html .

Comment: I'm not actually sure about the delimiter. Maybe a space?

Answer (score 0):

BBEdit has a “Run Unix Command” dialog box:

https://www.barebones.com/images/bbedit/run-unix-command-lg.png
https://www.barebones.com/products/bbedit/benefitsexercise.html

All that's left for you to do is pick a command line language to learn and work in. Typical choices include `sed`, `awk`, `perl`, and (my personal favorite) `raku`, formerly known as Perl_6. An advantage of Raku is high-level support for Unicode, including non-Latin scripts. Links to the offical Raku site, as well as a link to the Rakudo compiler, are provided at the bottom.

If you have Raku installed, you can run the following code in the “Run Unix Command” dialog box:

```
raku -e 'my @a = lines(); .join("\t").put for @a.batch(2);'
```

This will take the Sample Input:

```
Ryan Muramatsu
Corporate Venturing Co-Lead at Tokio Marine
Ryan Muramatsu
Corporate Venturing Co-Lead at Tokio Marine
```

...and convert it to (tab-separated) Sample Output:

```
Ryan Muramatsu  Corporate Venturing Co-Lead at Tokio Marine
Ryan Muramatsu  Corporate Venturing Co-Lead at Tokio Marine
```

You may need to do some pre-processing first. The code below removes blank lines:

```
raku -ne '.put if .chars;'
```

Run these commands individually, or sequentially with a `|` pipe operator between them:

```
raku -ne '.put if .chars;' | raku -e 'my @a = lines(); .join("\t").put for @a.batch(2);'
```

---

Your best choices for a separator include `","` comma (to create a simple-CSV file) or `"\t"` tab (to create a simple-TSV file). So adjust the code above accordingly. Either choice should enable you to import the resulting file into MS Excel or Apple's Numbers (iWork suite).

https://raku.org/
https://rakudo.org/

Comment: Okay, I should include in the question that it's consisting of not just 2 lines, but around 2000+ lines.

Comment: Updated original post.